# elisp pattern matching on symbols

Tags: pattern-matching, elisp, symbols

I have the following pattern matching expression in `elisp`:

```
 (pcase (cadr x)
        (S "\u2660")
        (D "\u2666")
        (C "\u2663")
        (H "\u2665") 
        (_ "error"))
```

Consider `(setq x (3 'H))`

Clearly, we would expect the output to match to "\u2665", but it is matching to "\u2660." which is the S. What is going on here? How can I get this pattern matching statement to match the correct symbol?

Thanks for all the help.

Comment: I found something with `C-h f pcase RET` saying that symbols match anything --- so this would be consistent with the behaviour I have found. Now can anyone verify that?

Comment: The pattern `S` means "match anything and bind it to the variable `S`".  To do what you want, you need to quote the symbol as `\`S` to indicate that you want to match the object `S`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a "QPattern" (see `C-h f pcase`) to match a particular symbol.  This worked for me:

```
(let ((x '(3 H)))
  (pcase (cadr x)
    (`S 1)
    (`H 3)
    (_ "error")))
;; => 3
```